# MsTeams pop out image is working in msteams web version but not working in mobile version

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've created a hero card that users get at the time of installing our app. In that I'm trying to put a popout image for a button. I've tried with this code.

```
CardFactory.heroCard(
      'Welcome to PeopleCues!',
      await this.getMessage(),
      [logo_url],
      [
        {
          type: ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
          title: 'connect',
          value: url,
          image: "https://okr-app-store.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/icons8-open-in-popup-32.png"
        }, 
        {
          type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
          title: 'Install app for all Org users',
          text: 'Install app for all Org users'
        },
        {
          type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
          title: 'help',
          text: 'help'
        }
      ]
    );
```

It shows pop out icon on the button beside the text in web version, but the same is not happening in msteams mobile app. This is a mandatory fix to pass the validation by MicrosoftAppSubmissionTeam, what can I do to reflect the same image in mobileapp as well

[image: card in msteams mobile app]?

above card in msteams mobile app.
[image: same card on web version msteams]

above card in msteams web app.

Comment: We are able to repro the issue. It shows pop out icon on the button beside the text in Teams web version, but the same is not happening in Teams mobile app. Attaching screenshots for reference: 1. Teams Web client: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTA6X.png 2. Mobile Client: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLgN0.png

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any further update. Thanks!